# android/phonegap 3.2 project fails to build after touching app.java

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I'm attempting to add a splash screen to my phonegap/meteor application.  The iOS version displays the default PG robot screens without any modification, and I was able to customize those screens by simply overwriting the defaults.  For android, however, I have followed the instructions in the PG docs, to no effect.  From http://devgirl.org/2013/09/12/phonegap-icons-and-splash-screens-help/, it seems like you need to modify the applications app.java file.

```
package com.myapp.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MyApp extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());

        //This is the line I'm supposed to add.
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash); 

        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, both in this case and when trying to mess with the fullscreen settings I've learned that changing this file will cause the build to fail:

```
> Error: An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant debug -f "/home/plandrem/myapp/myapp-phonegap/platforms/android/build.xml"": 
BUILD FAILED
/home/plandrem/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/plandrem/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

My best clue is that most of the previous solutions suggesting changes to app.java refer to a class called DroidGap, which has been deprecated by CordovaActivity.  My hunch is that the established solutions no longer work with this new class, in which case I have no idea what to do.  Has anyone been able to modify their main java file with the most recent version of phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

What seems to work is running a project>clean in Eclipse before building with the phonegap CLI.  I don't understand why, but the phonegap build process seems to create some conflict such that Eclipse thinks CordovaActivity doesn't exist.